# Counter exchanging limit and integral

Tags: integration, limits, physics, examples-counterexamples

**Background**

I came across [this answer on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335667/21820) which claimed it made a lot of sense to switch limit and integral. In response I came up with the following counter-examples:

- $\lim_{w \to 0} \int_0^\infty we^{-wt}\ dt = 1$ but $\int_0^\infty \lim_{w \to 0} we^{-wt}\ dt = 0$.
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!} e^{-t}\ dt = \infty$ but $\int_0^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!} e^{-t}\ dt = 0$.
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 n^3 t^n (1-t)\ dt = \infty$ but $\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} n^3 t^n (1-t)\ dt = 0$.
- $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{r(rx)^3}{(rx)^4-(rx)^3+1}\ dx = \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y^3}{y^4-y^3+1}\ dy \approx 2$ and $\lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{r(rx)^3}{(rx)^4-(rx)^3+1} = \frac{1}{x}$ for any $x \ne 0$. [Newly added]

Unlike the claimed method in that post, the first three counter-examples have continuous limit functions.

The third has the advantage of having the integral over a finite interval, to show that interchanging is still not valid without additional assumptions on the function sequence.

The fourth uses exactly the same technique as the claimed method (with a discontinuous limit function) and also gives an integral that is constant and independent of the limit!

Of course, these examples do not satisfy the dominated convergence theorem in various ways.

**Question**

Do you have any good counter-examples that actually show up in real-world problems and have an experimentally measurable implication for the real world? I somehow get the impression that the functions in the real-world might be too nice (wave functions are infinitely differentiable when you really factor everything in; in particular there are no such things as square potential wells because it is impossible to have a discontinuous change in potential!) I would be satisfied with examples in classical mechanics if the effect is measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the retarted propagator of a  free right moving quantum mechanical particle with linear dispersion

$$
G(\omega,k,\delta)=\frac{1}{\omega-vk+i \delta}
$$ 
(the $+i \delta$ is there for causality reasons and have set to  be $0$ in the end (in a limiting procedure))

Calculating the corresponding density of states requires the calculation of $\rho(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} dk G(k,\omega)$ which only makes sense if we calculate it like

$$
\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}} dk G(k,\omega,\delta)
$$

instead of

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} dk \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} G(k,\omega,\delta)
$$

(the second quantity clearly diverges). The reason is that we are handeling quantities which are strictly speaking only defined in a distributional sense.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this propagated straight over my head. Do you happen to know a simpler example?

Comment: i think similar arguments have to be made if one wants to find the Green's function for Poisson's equation via fourier transform

Comment: There are many examples in theoretical physics where the model calculation leads to an expression (say an integral or a sum), which in a mathematical sense is not strictly defined. However based on the validity of the model, it can often be argued that the expression must exist. It is then common to make some reasonable assumption. E.g. the spectrum must have a cut-off value, or there is small convergence factor. This step validates the computation and leads (hopefully) to an acceptable result. Pure mathematicians may frown at these procedures.

Comment: For example in Quantum Mechanics certain assumptions about particle interactions must be made, otherwise the model becomes too complicated. Yet these assumptions may result in a wave-function that does not have all the required properties. Physicist then routinely repair the wave-function in an ad-hoc manner. This process is called "regularization of  the wave-function".

Comment: @M.Wind: Sorry I don't buy any of those arbitrary cut-off stuff or regularization or renormalization.

Comment: @user21820 Then you are on my side!